# Base return type on input options

Tags: typescript

A `File` can have `content` set as a `string` or to a `Buffer` depending on if the encoding option is set.

I am trying to overload this function to gain the ability to determine what the result would be based on the input.

```
async function readFromFileQuery (fq: Merge<FileQuery, { encoding: FileEncodings }>): Promise<Merge<File, { content: string }>>;
async function readFromFileQuery (fq: Merge<FileQuery, { encoding: null }>): Promise<Merge<File, { content: Buffer }>>;
async function readFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
    const { path, encoding, flag } = FileQueryHandler.make(fq);
    const content = await promisify(fs.readFile)(path, { encoding, flag })
    return { path, encoding, flag, content };
}

readFromFileQuery({ path: './File.ts', encoding: FileEncodings.UTF8 }).then(r => {
    console.log(r);
});
```

How can I achieve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what all your types are but you can easily overload on a parameter if the shape of the parameter type is incompatible between the overloads.

This works as expected

```
import { promisify } from "util";
import * as fs from 'fs'


async function readFromFileQuery(fq: Merge<FileQuery, { encoding: FileEncodings }>): Promise<Merge<File, { content: string }>>;
async function readFromFileQuery (fq: Merge<FileQuery, { encoding?: null | undefined}>): Promise<Merge<File, { content: Buffer }>>;
async function readFromFileQuery (fq: FileQuery): Promise<File> {
    const { path, encoding, flag } = FileQueryHandler.make(fq);
    const content = await promisify(fs.readFile)(path, { encoding, flag })
    return { path, encoding: encoding as FileEncodings, flag, content };
}

readFromFileQuery({ path: './File.ts', encoding: FileEncodings.UTF8 }).then(r => {
    console.log(r.content); // string
});

readFromFileQuery({ path: './File.ts' }).then(r => {
  console.log(r.content); // Buffer
});

readFromFileQuery({ path: './File.ts', encoding: null }).then(r => {
  console.log(r.content); // Buffer
});

// Some assumptions
type Merge<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U 
enum FileEncodings {
  UTF8  ="UTF8"
}
interface FileQuery {
  path: string,  flag?: string, encoding?: FileEncodings | null
}
export interface File {
  path: string,  flag?: string, encoding: string, content: Buffer | string
}

declare var FileQueryHandler: {
  make(fq: FileQuery) : FileQuery
}
```